# How can I get boxes to snap into position when I drag and drop them into certain regions of the screen?

Tags: ios, swift

I am currently building a game on swift, using Storyboards. The game revolves around generating income from fishing lobsters. Users have lobster pots, which they can place into either inshore or outshone regions of the water. With no prior experience. I have minimal knowledge on how to code in swift.

My problem at the moment is understanding collision detection. There are three regions of the screen where the users can drag their pots into. The first screen is the starting position of the lobster pots, from which the player must drag the pots into either inshore or offshore locations. Currently, I have managed to code the action of dragging and dropping the pots, so they can be placed into any point on the screen. What I hope to do is to be able to have the pots to snap into position when the pots are dropped within the regions of either the inshore of offshore boxes. Furthermore, when the pots are dropped into place, I would like them to be organized in a row, equally spaced, and dropping into a row below, filling up the box.

Image -

[image: Starting position of the pots, before they are moved. The regions are labeled as "my pots", "inshore", and "outshore".]

I think I should also mention that the background is an image view, taken as a screenshot of the view when the game is running. I did this to avoid layering, as some pots would sometimes move behind the boxes when dragging them.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here some ideas:

You already have the code to move the tiles, that's good. All you now need is same math.
Although your background is an image, you also need some data model to keep, where your stuff is (or where your pots belong to). It is important to know, if a pot is in "My Pots" or "Inshor" or "Outshore". This information has to keep in some objects, like "myPots" and "inshore" and so on.
So dragging doesn't only move the pots on screen, it also changes where a pot belong to.

Hint: A representation of a area (myPots, ...) can be done with invisible areas. Invisible, because you already have the background. But a invisible rectangle gives you the ability to resize the ui without complicated re-calculations.

I would devide the area like this:

[image]

The coordinates are just examples for better understanding.
Most game engines work with coordinate (0,0) at top left.
So if you drag and release a pot, you have to calculate the end point of drag and compare it with your areas. No complicated collision detection necessary, because you only test if a point is in an area. But if you want collision detection, search for AABB collision detection (like here https://studiofreya.com/3d-math-and-physics/simple-aabb-vs-aabb-collision-detection/).

In your case it would be enough to have the decision:

```
if draggedPot.endCoordinate.y > 100 {
  // in or out shore
  if draggedPot.endCoordinate.x > 300 {
    // outshore
  }
  else {
    // inshore
  }
}
else {
  // still in myPots
}
```

I hope you get the idea :)

For arrange in a row it's also some math. Loop over the pots in an area, place one by one, always `start-x + width-of-pot + some space`. If this is greater than width of the area, set y to `height of pot + some space` and x starts at zero.